# Serial write Arduino

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I have a problem with the function Serial.write() I was testing my conection with python, and I can send numbers, words or letters, but when I try to send the value of variable the function Serial.write gives me an error. So could you tell me what is happening?

```
#define Pin A1
void setup() {
    pinMode(Pin, INPUT); 
    Serial.begin(9600); 
}
void loop() {
    String a = String(13);
    Serial.write(a);
    
}


ERROR
C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\avr\1.8.2\cores\arduino/Print.h:52:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'String' to 'const char*'

exit status 1
no matching function for call to 'HardwareSerial::write(String&)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if want to send string means you directly enter the string in serial.write().while giving the string directly into the serial.write() then it will take that string as const char* not as a string type

```
Serial.write("hello");
```

else you cannot send a string as directly in serial.write.you can use serial.print.use char array to send

```
Serial.write(MyString, sizeof(MyString));
```

else you can send every char

```
void writeString(String stringData) { // Used to serially push out a String with Serial.write()

  for (int i = 0; i < stringData.length(); i++)
  {
    Serial.write(stringData[i]);   // Push each char 1 by 1 on each loop pass
  }

}// end writeString
```

Answer (score 0):

`write` can only send a single byte (or a single char), an array of bytes (with explicitly provided length) or a nul terminated string (not the String object).

Looks like you want `Serial.print(a);` not `Serial.write(a);`.
Or maybe `Serial.write(a.c_str());` or just `Serial.print(13);`.

Since you don't want to get "34564342" when you send 34, 56, 434, 2, I advise you to send them as lines with `println` and then read lines in Python.